# get a valuw in mysql result with curly braces

Tags: mysql, json

I have a *mysql* result where one of the index value is like this:

```
a:3:{s:7:"user_id",s:10:"123456789",s:19"2016-07-21 05:34:15,}
```

Is this JSON? If so, how do I get the value of `s:7`?

Comment: Try jsonlint.com - no, it isn't JSON

Comment: @robin then what is it? I get this from a sql result

Comment: Not sure if it's a well known format but if it helps, the a:3 is that is an array (I'm guessing) with 3 children and the s:7 is that it's a string with 7 characters, but all of it is anonymous so the best you could parse it to is an array of 3 strings.

Comment: It is just a string - it looks like it wants to be JSON - but it isn't...

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar - agree - but the trailing comma would produce an array of 4 with the final element being a null :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a php serialized array. You can deserialize with this if you're using php:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php